# How to get the full query that a PreparedStatement is about to execute in DB2?

Tags: java, eclipse, db2, prepared-statement

I'm working on a dynamic web project and using the PreparedStatement to execute the SQL queries against the DB2 database.

```
String myQuery = "select id from user where name = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt  = connection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
stmt.setString(1, test);
ResultSet resultSet  = statement.executeQuery();
```

How can I receive the full SQL query that is about to be executed on the DB2 server in the console?

Comment: depends on the driver, this may or may not work. try `stmt.toString()`. there is no native support for this. `PreparedStatement` is an interface and does not require implementation of such functionality.

Comment: If you don't succeed in java, talk with your DBA who can get DB2 to report the dynamic-SQL and the values of the parameter-marker variables. The mechanism the DBA uses will depend on the operating-system on which the DB2 server runs (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows) along with the DB2-version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with Debugging options in Eclipse. You may try the following:

1. Set a Breakpoint at `ResultSet resultSet  = statement.executeQuery();`
2. Right click your application, say `Debug As` select `Java Application` (or Whatever applicable in your case i.e. may be SpringBoot App etc.
3. Perform step that gets you to code mentioned in the Question.
4. If you check `Variables tab` in `Debug Perspective` of Eclipse, you will find variables like `myQuery` , `stmt` (according to your code)
5. Whatever you see as value of `stmt` would be the full SQL query you need.

Also, if you don't want to keep looking at this variable always you may try `Java Logging` and Print your Full SQL query in Logs.

Comment: Thank you rdj7 for the solution, I tried the above steps and now can see the expected results.

Comment: Great @chimbu !!